# Average of vectors with unknowns

Tags: vectors, average

I need to find an average of several vectors that denote the user profile. Here is the exmaple. '-' denotes that this element is empty. I computed the average, considering the '-' elements as well, so that for 1st element average is: $(1+9)/3=3.33$. Is it the correct way of doing it? I have doubts due to that empty elements. 
\begin{array}{llllllll}
    & 1   & 2   & 3   & 4 & 5 & 6   & 7    \\
v1  & 1   & -   & 3   & 2 & 1 & -   & -    \\
v2  & -   & 4   & 2   & 1 & 2 & -   & 7    \\
v3  & 9   & -   & 5   & - & - & 7   & 10   \\
ave & 3.3 & 1.3 & 3.3 & 1 & 1 & 2.3 & 5.66
\end{array}

Comment: Some additional context would help.  Is this homework, or is this a task that you're trying to design and engineer for a practical application?  If the former, then you need to figure out the "correct" interpretation; if the latter, then you have some leeway in deciding what's correct to make the result useful.

Comment: It's the second case. But yeah, seems that I'll co on with experimenting and see, what is more reliable .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is that all the information that's provided?  You might need to ask for some clarification on what the empty elements really signify.

If it's empty because there's no value (and not because the value is zero), you should probably divide by the number of non-empty values.  For instance, for the first column, you would compute

$$
\frac{1+9}{2} = 5
$$

If it's empty because that's the convention for a zero, then you can divide by $3$.  But that seems less likely to me.

Comment: That's why actually I asked the question. As I said, I had doubts on that I am considering empty as zero. That's all information, since I am getting several vectors, denoting the profile for the item, where each element is a score for a concept describing that item. And I need to find a final user profile, which is normalized sum of all profiles